# React Component Not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is wrong with the code below, it always logs 1. It receives a number in props and I just want to loop that many times to return a list of links.

```
import React from 'react';

const itemWidget = (props) => {

  let numItems = props.numItems;
  let itemList = itemMarkup(numItems);

  return (
    <div>

     { itemList } 

    </div>);
};

export default itemWidget;

const itemMarkup = (n) =>  {

  for (let i=1; i <= n ; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    return (
      <a href="#">{i}</a>
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the parent component's code that is passing in the number.

```
import React from 'react';
import itemWidget from '~/Components/itemWidget';

export default class Merchandise extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <div>
      <div className="merch-items">
        <ItemsWidget numItems={10}/>
      </div>
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `n` when it's passed in? Is it logging 1 multiple times, or once?

Comment: How are you invoking this component?  Can you provide the code where you are assign the prop value of numItems to it?

Comment: I have added code above for the parent component.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I see 1 four times, which I think has something to do with the lifecycle of the component, the page shows "1" just one time.

Answer (score 0):

**return** statement in *for* loop causing the loop to break.

Use following

```
import React from 'react';
const itemWidget = (props) => {

  let numItems = props.numItems;
  let itemList = itemMarkup(numItems);

  return (
    <div>

     { itemList } 

    </div>);
};
const itemMarkup = (n) =>  {
  let itemList  = [];
  for (let i=1; i <= n ; i++) {
    itemList.push (
      <a href="#">{i}</a>
    );
  }

  return itemList
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?

Comment: @SterlingArcher return statement in his for loop causing the loop to break.

Comment: In add that to the answer please :) A good answer has a good explanation to why it fixes the question, otherwise it's a code dump.

Answer (score 0):

```
const itemMarkup = (n) =>  {
  let rows = []
  for (let i=1; i <= n ; i++) {
      console.log(i);
      rows.push(<a href="#">{i}</a>);
    // return (
    //   <a href="#">{i}</a>
    // );
  }

    return rows;
};
```

return an array of links

Comment: yes but I don't want an array, i just want to loop a number of time to generate some links.

Comment: and I can probably work with this, create an array and then use map to produce html but I want to know why is it that what I have is not working.

Comment: because the itemMarkup arrow function just returned, it breaks the for loop. So only the first element you can get.

Comment: Everyone is saying the for loop breaks but no one is explaining why is it breaking, I'm sure there is an explanation, is this something related to JSX ? something I can read about?